# Prove random variables are not almost surely equal, but are equal in distributions

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have a probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B},m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure of the unit interval.

With this, how would I prove that random variables, say $X,Y: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are not almost surely equal, but are equal in distribution?

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution): Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not equal almost surely iff $\mathbb{P}(X\ne Y)>0$, while they are equal in distribution if they have the same distribution functions: $\mathbb{P}(X\le x)=\mathbb{P}(Y\le x)$

Comment: There's no single way to do it - it depends on what information you have about X and Y. Use that information to prove both of the statements you need.

Comment: For intuition: two fair dice are equal in distribution (both being fair) but are not almost surely equal (since you don't always roll doubles).

Comment: @Karl Well I have that $X: x \rightarrow 2x^2+1$, but I have to come up with a Y.

Comment: Cool. Given a similar function for Y, do you know how to calculate $P(X\ne Y)$, $P(X\le x)$, and $P(Y\le x)$?

Comment: Intuitively what you're looking for is a function Y that has the same "distribution of values" as X but not in the same places in the probability space. Since your space is $[0,1]$, consider replacing $x$ with $1-x$ in the definition of $X$.

Comment: $P(X\le x) = \int_0^x Xdm$ and $P(Y\le x) = \int_0^x Ydm$, not sure about showing $P(X\ne Y)$

Comment: By definition, $P(X\ne Y)=m(\{x\in [0,1]|X(x)\ne Y(x)\})$.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to ask:

> "how would I prove that random variables $X,Y$ exist that are not almost surely equal but do have equal distribution"

then let $X,Y:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto 1-x$ respectively.

Here $\{X=Y\}=\left\{\frac12\right\}$ so that $P(X\neq Y)=1$ and it is evident that $X$ and $Y$ both have uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.